# Ajuda com código JS

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse código:

```
        if(post.link[k].type == 'post miniatura'){
          var postMiniatura = post.link[k].href;
        } else {
          var postImage;
          try {
            postImage = post.media$image.url
          } catch (error) {
            s = post.content.$t;
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
            c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
              postImage = d
            }
          }
        }
```

O que eu tentei fazer foi o seguinte: Caso o `post.link[k].type` seja "post miniatura" ele executa o código e para, ou seja, não executa o restante que esta após o `else`. Só que o que acontece é que mesmo que `post.link[k].type` seja verdadeiro, ele executa o código depois do else também. Queria que o que esta depois de else fosse executado apenas se `post.link[k].type` não fosse igual a "post miniatura". O que eu faço? (sou iniciante em JS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito simples. Utilizando a sua lógica, você pode colocar um `return` após `var postMiniatura = post.link[k].href;`.
Dessa forma, você vai sair da função JS e não executar o que há depois do `else`.